# How to center absolute position heading without wrapping + using pseudo class :before

Tags: css, css-position, absolute

i have following H2 element "základní operace"

I use pseudo class `::before` for creating underline.

```css
h2 {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: var(--fs-xl);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
}

h2:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  height: 1px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 10%;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #007bff;
}
```

```html
<h2>
  Zakladni operace
</h2>
```

Everything for 1 word heading looks great but for 2 and more words headings like "základní operace" it's wrapping.. There is no reason in this case i have lot of space around as you can see below in the picture.

How can i center it in this case? I need keep absolute position for pseudo class. Without pseudo class `::before` i'd just simply set `text-align center`

[image]

Comment: Did you try increasing the `h2` `width`?

Comment: I have multiple H2 headings and i need underline width 80% of H2. So i can't increase width manualy cuz some shorter heading will have too long underlines

Comment: Can you try to set `width: max-content;` of h2 element and see if that works for you...

Comment: Although you say there is lots of space so it needn't wrap, it looks as though you have margins on things - looking at the subsequent text. Could you include a runnable snippet which actually shows the problem because there isn't enough information in the code you have given for us to be able to work out what the problem is. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Add `width: 100%;` to your h2. It worked when I just tested your snippet. Alternately, if you specifically want to prevent a line break you could also add `white-space: nowrap;`.

```css
h2 {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: var(--fs-xl);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}

h2:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  height: 1px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 10%;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #007bff;
}
```

```html
<h2>
  Zakladni operace
</h2>
```